# Installing R 4.0.3 on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install R 4.0.3 on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.10 64-bit. It is fully updated.

Before I did anything, I added the correct CRAN repository for this OS using `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu groovy-cran40/'`.

When I run `sudo apt install r-base`, I get an error that **r-base-core** and **r-recommendrf**, both of which are specified to require version `>= 4.0.3-1.2010.0`, are "not going to be installed".

Checking them individually, it seems that **r-base-core** is the problem. If I try to install **r-recommended** by itself, I get an error that it needs "r-base-core (>= 4.0.3-1.2010.0) but 4.0.2-1build1 is to be installed".

If I check https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/groovy-cran40/, I notice that **r-base-core** 4.0.3 is only available in an AMD64 variant, per the **amd64** in the filenames. I observe that the **r-base** package's files do not have **amd64** in their filenames. To me, that suggests that, currently, you're only running R 4.0.3 on Ubuntu 20.10 if you are on an Intel/AMD 64-bit platform. https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/groovy-cran40/Packages seems to back that up.

Are there practical alternatives, other than to wait for an **r-base-core** 4.0.3 package to appear that is compatible with more platforms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. Most of the credit goes to Andrés Castro Socolich, who [provided](https://community.rstudio.com/t/installing-r-4-0-3-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-ubuntu-20-10/89369) most of the solution.

This assumes a mostly vanilla Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.10 64-bit installed:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt ugrade
sudo apt-get install -y g++ gfortran libreadline6-dev libx11-dev libxt-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libcairo2-dev xvfb libbz2-dev libzstd-dev liblzma-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev texinfo texlive texlive-fonts-extra screen wget libpcre2-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libpcre2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev openjdk-11-jdk make
cd /usr/local/src
sudo wget https://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-4/R-4.0.3.tar.gz
sudo su
tar zxvf R-4.0.3.tar.gz
cd R-4.0.3
./configure --enable-R-shlib
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf R-4.0.3*
exit
cd
```

Comment: I had to add `apt-get install g++` in order for `./configure` to succeed and move onto the next step

Comment: Thank you. I confirmed it is installed. I remotely remember installing it before this for another reason.

Comment: It was also missing **make**. Now both it and **g++** are included in the **apt-get install** command.

Comment: I'm sorry this might be a stupid question, but how exactly do I run it from here? It seems to have installed successfully (no errors), but `rstudio` doesn't work from the terminal. how do I go about this?

Comment: @RedFox if it's not in your path, then either add it to your path or specify the path first.